# Kotlin Array Slice Indexing

Tags: kotlin

Let's say I want to iterate through all but the first element in Kotlin `IntArray`. Currently, I'm doing it like this:

```kotlin
fun minimalExample(nums: IntArray): Unit {
    for(num in nums.sliceArray(IntRange(1,nums.size-1))) println(num)
}
```

Is there an easy syntax for doing this like in Python (I don't want to have to specify the ending index of the `nums` array):

```py
for (num in nums[1:])
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think you could use Kotlin's [`drop`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/drop.html) which will remove the first `n` elements of an array.

```
fun minimalExampleWithDrop(nums: IntArray): Unit {
    for(num in nums.drop(1)) println(num)
}

minimalExampleWithDrop(intArrayOf(1,2,3,4,5,6))
// 2
// 3
// 4
// 5
// 6
```

Repl.it: 
https://repl.it/repls/SvelteShadyLivecd

Comment: Drop will change the `IntArray` into a `List<Int>`, if you need an `IntArray` you'll have to convert that back.

Comment: It doesn't change the original. It creates a copy of the data in a new list that you can optionally keep a reference to.

Comment: For reference (from @robstackoverflow's answer: drop: https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/drop.html dropLast: https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/drop-last.html

Answer (score 8):

You can alternatively also use the `slice` method which is present in lists and arrays. Here are examples for both:

```
val a = listOf(1, 2, 3, 4)
println(a.slice(1..a.size - 1))

val b = arrayOf(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)
println(b.slice(4..5))
```

This will print out:

```
[2, 3, 4]
[5, 6]
```

Answer (score 3):

A basic [for loop](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/kotlin-for-py/loops.html#for) with `1` as starting index

```
    val myList = intArrayOf(1,2,3,4,5,6)

    for(i in 1 until myList.size){
        Log.d(TAG,"${myList[i]}")
    }
```

Or since it's an `IntArray` you can use it as an `Iterator` and skip elements like shown [here](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/for-each.html)

```
    val iterator = myList.iterator()
    // skip an element
    if (iterator.hasNext()) {
        iterator.next()
    }
    iterator.forEach {
        Log.d(TAG,"it -> $it")
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to @gil.fernandes answer, you can use `slice` with `until` like this:

```
val list = arrayOf(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)
println(list.slice(0 until 5))
```

This will output:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```